# using xltabular to break over multiple pages results in a list of tables with multiple entries for the same table

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, xltabular

I am using `xltabular` to break a table over multiple pages. When I use `\caption` for the table, It produces a caption for each page that the table is on. I do not need this behavior, but can look passed it. However, it does produce multiple entries in my `LoT`. That behavior is expected if its creating new captions on every page; but it is behavior that i cannot continue with.

Is there anyway to get a `xltabular` to break over pages, but not re-caption everything? or is there a way to tell `\listoftables` to not display duplicates?

below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\section{test}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|X|}

            \caption{Connector Pin Designation}\\ \hline


            % Create the header
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\ \hline
            \endhead \hline % Finish the header

            \endfoot \hline  % Finish the footer (nothing here)



            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\


\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Which results in the following list of tables.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

By using (relative new) package `tabularray your problems cannot happen:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\section{test}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Connector Pin Designation},
  label = {tab:longtblr},
                ]{
    vlines,
    colspec = {c c c X[j]},
    row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
    rowhead = 1  }
% table body
    \toprule
test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\ 
    \midrule
test1 & test2 & test3 & \lipsum[66] \\
test1 & test2 & test3 & \lipsum[66] \\
test1 & test2 & test3 & \lipsum[66] \\
test1 & test2 & test3 & \lipsum[66] \\
test1 & test2 & test3 & \lipsum[66] \\
test1 & test2 & test3 & \lipsum[66] \\
test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Test of caption numbering}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

A description of syntax `tabularray` can be found in its documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using different `\caption` commands for the caption on the first and the following pages can help here.

I have used an empty optional argument for the captions that are shwon on the following pages to suppress these from showing in the list of tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\section{test}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|X|}

            \caption{Connector Pin Designation}
            \\ \hline
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\ \hline
            \endfirsthead
            \caption[]{Connector Pin Designation}\\ \hline
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\ \hline
            \endhead 
            \hline
            \endfoot   % Finish the footer (nothing here)
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\


\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am was hoping that I wouldn't have to do that. It feels kind of like a hack (just blank out the caption). So I played around a little bit with the new commands that you have in your response. It turns out that you don't need to add the second caption at all. you just need a `\endfirstheader` with the caption, then a `\endheader` without a caption.

Comment: @AlexSchultz: Leaving out the second caption command entirely will definitely work. You will however loose the caption on the following pages with this approach. Since you used `\endhead` in your original  question, I was under the impression you wanted the caption to repeat on every page of the table.

Comment: @leandriis, (i) you not need to correct `table` counter, (ii) your table preamble has errors, correct is: `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|X|}
\caption{Connector Pin Designation}\\
    \hline
test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\ 
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Connector Pin Designation}\\ 
    \hline
test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\ \hline
    \endhead
\hline  % Finish the footer (nothing here)
    \endfoot
% table body`

Comment: @Zarko: Prior to version `0.2d` of the `xltabular` package, a second caption incorrectly increased the table counter, hence the correction in the previous version of my answer. With the most recent version of `xltabular` this correction isn't needed any more. I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`xltabular` uses the commands `\endfirsthead` and `endhead`. These can help you in your search.

`\endfirsthead` designates the first header as something different than what is printed on the rest of the page. The `\caption` command will also be included in this header.

`\endhead` works the same as the `\endfirsthead` but on every page that the table breaks to. So if you put a `\caption` here, then it will print a caption of every page.

Here is your MWE with the proper fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\section{test}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|X|}

            \caption{Connector Pin Designation}\\ \hline


            % Create the first header
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            \endfirsthead \hline % Finish the header


            % Create the header for the rest of the pages
            % (if you leave this out, then you wont get headers on
            %  your pages.) 

            % dont add a \caption
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            \endhead \hline % Finish the header


            \endfoot \hline  % Finish the footer (nothing here)



            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\
            test1 & test2 & test3 & test4 \\


\end{xltabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]